# Action not being triggered for UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift

first post so apologies if I mess something up.  I have researched this for hours upon hours and read other posts here on stack exchange to no avail.

I have created a nib file that defines a custom view and have defined a custom class (UIView) to manage the outlets of the custom view.  As you can see from the code below excerpted from my custom UIView class associated with the nib, I have a date picker as the input view for the custom class and a UIToolBar with two UIBarButtonItems.  Both of these appear as desired through a tap gesture recognizer... however the problem is the UIBarButtonItems do not call the action when tapped.  Placing a breakpoint in the action function reveals that the code is never run.  I feel that something with the view lifecycle is preventing a reference from being made, but I am new to Swift so some help here would be appreciated.  I don't think it is selector syntax as the tap gesture recognizer works as desired.  I've tried messing with button click handling access levels.  I've tried doing input view setup when the view awakes from the nib as well, along with trying to put the code in different parts of the lifecycle.

If it matters for lifecycle's sake, this nib is a part of a table view cell.  I call for this nib to be loaded when the table view cell awakes from it's nib.

Thanks!

```
@IBOutlet weak var timerStackView: UIStackView!{
    didSet{
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HandleTap(_:)))
        timerStackView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }
}

var datePicker: UIDatePicker {
    let picker = UIDatePicker()
    picker.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    picker.isOpaque = false
    picker.setValue(UIColor.white, forKey: "textColor")
    return picker
}

var datePickerAccessoryView: UIToolbar {
    let accessoryView = UIToolbar()
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(handleDatePickerButtonClick(_:)))
    doneButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleDatePickerButtonClick(_:)))
    cancelButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
    accessoryView.setItems([cancelButton, doneButton], animated: true)
    return accessoryView
}

override var inputView: UIView? {return datePicker}
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {return datePickerAccessoryView}
override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {return true}
override var canResignFirstResponder: Bool {return true}

// MARK: - Private functions
@objc fileprivate func HandleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
    if !self.isFirstResponder {
        switch sender.state {
        case .ended:
            datePicker.date = Date()
            self.becomeFirstResponder()
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

@objc @IBAction internal func handleDatePickerButtonClick(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) -> Void {
    switch sender.title! {
    case "Done":
        // To be implemented
    case "Cancel":
        // To be implemented
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initialising the `UIToolbar` without a frame and that would make it not register any touch events because they would be out of the toolbar's bounds.

Replace `let accessoryView = UIToolbar()` with something like `let accessoryView = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: 44))`

Or you can call `accessoryView.sizeToFit()` before `return accessoryView`

Comment: Tried this line of code, still didn't fix the problem :/

Comment: @EdManning Sorry about that, check the updated answer. This should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! This did it.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the tap gesture recognizer is interfering with native UIBarButtonItem click events. But why do you use a gesture recognizer for that?

You should better add an action to each particular UIBarButtonItem.

Comment: the gesture recognizer is to make the view the first responder, so that the input view can be made visible.  Is there a better way for me to set up this code?

Comment: Yeap, you can use view.becomeFirstResponder() for the view you want to focus on. To be more specific, I guess the code should be written in viewWillAppear, rather than viewDidLoad. But you could check it by your own.

Comment: But I would like the input view to appear specifically when the user taps on the view, not when the view loads or appears... do I not need a tap gesture recognizer to achieve this?